# Local notification behaviour

Tags: iphone, ios

When my application is not active (in background) I recive local notification. After click on this notification application became active. Is it possible to activate application after I recive local notification automaticaly, without clicking on it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this is not possible.
From [Local and Push Notification Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH1-SW1)

> If there is a notification alert and **the user taps or clicks the
>   action button (or moves the action slider)**, the application launches
>   and calls a method to pass in the local-notification object or
>   remote-notification payload.

An action performed by the user is required.

Answer (score 1):

**No**, you cannot start any application automatically from background without user getting some actions.

So, for local notifications, application cannot be resumed from background even if local notification is fired. User has to click on notification to open application.